# "is great for playing chess and meeting friends" or "is great to play chess and meet with friends"?

Tags: gerunds, present-simple

I want to tell you that now is good weather for the next types of activities.

I guess I should use next variant:

> The weather is great for playing chess and meeting friends.

Instead of:

> The weather is excellent to play chess and meet with friends.

Both of them are present simple in the first case. I use gerunds because I express my preferences.
Am I right?

Comment: **The weather is great for VERB-ing** is much more fluent and idiomatic.  I don't think it has anything to do with expressing a preference, though.  "I like to run" also expresses a preference and uses the to-infinitive and not the gerund.

Comment: @stangdon you understood me so well. Your comment clear to me. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I agree with your conclusion, but not with your reason.

It's nothing to do with your preferences: it is purely a syntactic matter. *Good to (verb)* (in this sense) cannot take a lexical subject.

You can say

> **It** is good to play chess.

or

> The weather is good to play chess **in**.

but not

> *The weather is good to play chess.

Similarly, you can say

> **It** is good to play chess **with him**.

or

> He is good to play chess **with**.

but not

> *He is good to play chess.